# How to revert AIX service pack?

Tags: aix, patch-management

I have an [AIX 6.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX#Versions) box with service pack level 6100-02-03-0909

```
swax23 # oslevel -s -q
```

### Known Service Packs

6100-02-03-0909
6100-02-02-0849
6100-02-01-0847
6100-02-00-0000
6100-01-04-0909
6100-01-03-0846
6100-01-02-0834
6100-01-01-0823
6100-00-08-0909
6100-00-07-0846
6100-00-06-0834
6100-00-05-0822
6100-00-04-0815
6100-00-03-0808
6100-00-02-0750
6100-00-01-0748

I want to revert the latest serive pack and go back to 6100-02-02-0849.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Restoring a mksysb image from the system?

Answer (score 1):

How the TL/SP works internally in AIX, the SP is nothing more than a collection of rules:

```
fileset x.y.z should be at version >=6.7.8.9 (if installed at all)
fileset a.b.c should be at version >=6.0.0.3 (if installed at all)
...
```

These rules can be checked via instfix command. If at least one rule is not fulfilled, it means you don't have this SP level, but a lower one. For example, if you will now install some old fileset, you might notice that "oslevel -s" will show lower SP level. This is by design.

So really, what you ask is probably how to lower some versions of filesets.
The first thing I would try is to list **uncommited** filesets in smitty. These filesets have updates that may be **rejected** (i.e. the system still has the original files, and can revert to earlier version). Only when you commit the filesets it removes the original versions of files. When updating AIX the default smitty setting is, unfortunately, to automatically commit.

Next thing to try is restore the backup.

The last resort is to try to reinstall all filesets to the original version using original installation media. This will probably preserve contents of various configuration files. I haven't done it and it is surely not a standard operation. It might be even impossible because of complicated set of dependencies between system filesets.

May I ask what went wrong with TL02 SP3?